# Network error / timeout on device

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using Firebase on iOS, and everything is working fine in the simulator. However on my device, any calls I make to Firebase result in this error:

> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901017] Encounter network error.
>   Code, error: -1001, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The
>   request timed out."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:12345678910:ios:ce62efd99672cf34?platform=ios&app_instance_id=AEC5F2D2ECB647278490FAE79B2594&gmp_version=3700,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:7434851695:ios:ce62efd99672cf34?platform=ios&app_instance_id=AEC5F2D2ECB647278490FAE79B259&gmp_version=3700,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2103, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}

(I've tweaked some of the unique numbers in this snippet for privacy)

Any idea why I am getting this network error from Firebase when running on the device?

Edit: This is happening when the device is connected to a VPN. Any suggested ways of handling this? If any.

Comment: check firewall rules or use telnet.

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev Interesting, I was just going to edit my post to say that this was happening when I'm on a VPN.

Comment: @vikzilla am getting the same error. could tell how to handle this error messages. What is caused for these errors? I'm not using VPN.